# Consul nodes and service are not getting created/updated in the same terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, consul, harshicorp

We are creating couple of consul records with the terraform code. We’ve observed this behaviour of consul service not being available in the 1st attempt (host is not reachable even though terraform execution is successful) and the record being pointed correctly in the subsequent execution. This happens because consul nodes are created in the 1st attempt and consul service in the next attempt.
In case of Consul node replacement is causing Consul Service deletion which is not handled throught Terraform. When the consul node replacement is carried out by terraform, it's automatically triggering consul service deletion outside Terraform control as a result of which TF on the second run complains with

`Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform`

**Following are the logs of terraform apply:**

**1st execution (deleting existing records to create new ones)**

```
***** used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
-/+ destroy and then create replacement
 <= read (data resources)

***** will perform the following actions:

  # data.aws_broker_nodes.brokers will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
 <= data "aws_broker_nodes" "brokers"  {
      ~ id             = "arn:aws:*****" -> (known after apply)
      ~ node_info_list = [
          - {
              - attached_eni_id       = "eni-*****"
              - broker_id             = 1
              - client_subnet         = "subnet-*****"
              - client_vpc_ip_address = "XX.XX.XX.XX"
              - endpoints             = [
                  - "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
                ]
              - node_arn              = "arn:aws:*****"
            },
          - {
              - attached_eni_id       = "eni-*****"
              - broker_id             = 2
              - client_subnet         = "subnet-*****"
              - client_vpc_ip_address = "XX.XX.XX.XX"
              - endpoints             = [
                  - "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
                ]
              - node_arn              = "arn:aws:*****"
            },
          - {
              - attached_eni_id       = "eni-*****"
              - broker_id             = 3
              - client_subnet         = "subnet-*****"
              - client_vpc_ip_address = "XX.XX.XX.XX"
              - endpoints             = [
                  - "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
                ]
              - node_arn              = "arn:aws:*****"
            },
        ] -> (known after apply)
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
    }

  # aws_security_group.sg will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
      ~ egress                 = [
          - {
              - cidr_blocks      = [
                  - "127.0.0.1/32",
                ]
              - description      = "Blocking outbound connections"
              - from_port        = 2
              - ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              - prefix_list_ids  = []
              - protocol         = "tcp"
              - security_groups  = []
              - self             = false
              - to_port          = 2
            },
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "127.0.0.1/32",
                ]
              + description      = "Blocking outbound connections"
              + from_port        = 3
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 3
            },
        ]
        id                     = "sg-*****"
        name                   = "sgrp-*****"
        # (7 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # consul_node.consul_node[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "consul_node" "consul_node" {
      ~ address    = "*****eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      ~ datacenter = "******" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id         = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
      - meta       = {} -> null
        name       = "b1-*****"
    }

  # consul_node.consul_node[1] must be replaced
-/+ resource "consul_node" "consul_node" {
      ~ address    = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      ~ datacenter = "******" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id         = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
      - meta       = {} -> null
        name       = "b2-*****"
    }

  # consul_node.consul_node[2] must be replaced
-/+ resource "consul_node" "consul_node" {
      ~ address    = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      ~ datacenter = "******" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id         = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
      - meta       = {} -> null
        name       = "b3-*****"
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 1 to change, 3 to destroy.
----------------------
consul_node.consul_node[2]: Destroying... [id=*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com]
consul_node.consul_node[0]: Destroying... [id=*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com]
consul_node.consul_node[1]: Destroying... [id=*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com]
consul_node.consul_node[2]: Destruction complete after 0s
consul_node.consul_node[1]: Destruction complete after 0s
consul_node.consul_node[0]: Destruction complete after 0s
data.aws_instance_nodes.instances: Reading... [id=*****]
aws_configuration.configuration: Modifying... [id=*****]
data.aws_instance_nodes.instances: Read complete after 0s [id=*****]
consul_node.consul_node[0]: Creating...
consul_node.consul_node[1]: Creating...
consul_node.consul_node[2]: Creating...
consul_node.consul_node[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com]
consul_node.consul_node[2]: Creation complete after 0s [id=*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com]
consul_node.consul_node[1]: Creation complete after 0s [id=*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com]
aws_security_group.msk_sg: Modifications complete after 0s [id=sg-*****]
Apply complete! Resources: 3 added, 1 changed, 3 destroyed.
```

In the tf logs, it does not do anything to consul service, however, we checked on consul web ui; the corresponding consul service entry is deleted.

**2nd execution (Create consul service)**

```
Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the
last "terraform apply":

  # consul_node.consul_node[2] has been changed
  ~ resource "consul_node" "consul_node" {
        id         = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
      + meta       = {}
        name       = "b3-*****"
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
  # consul_node.consul_node[0] has been changed
  ~ resource "consul_node" "consul_node" {
        id         = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
      + meta       = {}
        name       = "b1-*****"
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
  # consul_node.consul_node[1] has been changed
  ~ resource "consul_node" "consul_node" {
        id         = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
      + meta       = {}
        name       = "b2-*****"
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
  # consul_service.consul_service[0] has been deleted
  - resource "consul_service" "consul_service" {
      - address             = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> null
      - datacenter          = "*****" -> null
      - enable_tag_override = false -> null
      - id                  = "*****" -> null
      - meta                = {} -> null
      - name                = "*****" -> null
      - node                = "b1-*****" -> null
      - port                = ***** -> null
      - service_id          = "*****" -> null
    }
  # consul_service.consul_service[1] has been deleted
  - resource "consul_service" "consul_service" {
      - address             = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> null
      - datacenter          = "*****" -> null
      - enable_tag_override = false -> null
      - id                  = "*****" -> null
      - meta                = {} -> null
      - name                = "*****" -> null
      - node                = "b2-*****" -> null
      - port                = ***** -> null
      - service_id          = "*****" -> null
    }
  # consul_service.consul_service[2] has been deleted
  - resource "consul_service" "consul_service" {
      - address             = "*****.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -> null
      - datacenter          = "*****" -> null
      - enable_tag_override = false -> null
      - id                  = "*****" -> null
      - meta                = {} -> null
      - name                = "*****" -> null
      - node                = "b3-*****" -> null
      - port                = ***** -> null
      - service_id          = "*****" -> null
    }

Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the
relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include
actions to undo or respond to these changes.

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # consul_service.consul_service[0] will be created
  + resource "consul_service" "consul_service" {
      + address    = (known after apply)
      + datacenter = (known after apply)
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + name       = "*****"
      + node       = "b1-*****"
      + port       = *****
      + service_id = (known after apply)
    }

  # consul_service.consul_service[1] will be created
  + resource "consul_service" "consul_service" {
      + address    = (known after apply)
      + datacenter = (known after apply)
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + name       = "*****"
      + node       = "b2-*****"
      + port       = *****
      + service_id = (known after apply)
    }

  # consul_service.consul_service[2] will be created
  + resource "consul_service" "consul_service" {
      + address    = (known after apply)
      + datacenter = (known after apply)
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + name       = "*****"
      + node       = "b3-*****"
      + port       = *****
      + service_id = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
------
consul_service.consul_service[2]: Creating...
consul_service.consul_service[1]: Creating...
consul_service.consul_service[0]: Creating...
consul_service.consul_service[2]: Creation complete after 0s [id=*****]
consul_service.consul_service[1]: Creation complete after 0s [id=*****]
consul_service.consul_service[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=*****]
Apply complete! Resources: 3 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Corresponding terraform code for creating these consul records is:

```
resource "consul_node" "consul_node" {
  count   = var.number_of_instances
  name    = "b${count.index + 1}-abc"
  address = flatten(data.instance_nodes.instances.node_info_list[*].endpoints)[count.index]
}

resource "consul_service" "consul_service" {
  count = var.number_of_instances
  name  = "abc"
  node  = consul_node.consul_node[count.index].name
  port  = *****
  tags  = ["****"]
}
```

```
Terraform version: v0.15.5
Consul provider version: 2.15.0
```

Are we missing any config because of which this is getting executed in 2 steps? Any possible bugs in `terraform-consul-provider`?

Comment: To answer this question it would help to see Terraform's full plan output, because that will typically give clues as to why Terraform is proposing to make certain changes.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Added complete output from tf execution. Just redacted the resource information. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You may consider upgrading Terraform to a version supported by the consul provider, before spending too many more cycles debugging: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/consul/latest/docs#compatibility

Comment: @MartinAtkins Does that give any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this seems to be caused by a quirk of Consul's behavior that the Terraform provider cannot represent accurately: it seems that deleting a node that is associated with a service implicitly deletes that service, without requiring an explicit request to delete the service.

Because of this, it seems to the `hashicorp/consul` provider that the services were "deleted outside of Terraform", because the provider didn't explicitly delete them but yet they are gone.

Because the service objects are connected to the node objects by name, the Consul provider can't tell that nodes are being replaced when it's planning the services: the name of the new node is the same as the name of the old node, so as far as the `consul_service` resources are concerned the nodes are not changing.

Because of all this, I think in this case you'll need to give Terraform a hint to help it understand that replacing the nodes also requires replacing the services:

```
resource "consul_node" "consul_node" {
  count   = var.number_of_instances
  name    = "b${count.index + 1}-abc"
  address = flatten(data.instance_nodes.instances.node_info_list[*].endpoints)[count.index]
}

resource "consul_service" "consul_service" {
  count = var.number_of_instances
  name  = "abc"
  node  = consul_node.consul_node[count.index].name
  port  = *****
  tags  = ["****"]

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = consul_node.consul_node
  }
}
```

[The `replace_triggered_by` lifecycle argument](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#replace_triggered_by) tells Terraform that if anything changes about the nodes then the services must be replaced.

---

Unfortunately this feature is imprecise because it wasn't really intended to deal with this particular situation. Using `replace_triggered_by` as I showed above means that any time *any* of the nodes change Terraform will plan to replace *all* of the services, since Terraform alone (without the provider's help) cannot understand the relationships between the nodes and the services, so it can't understand that one node correlates with one service.

This means that each time you change a single node there will be a brief period where your services have been deleted, but then they'll be re-registered shortly afterwards. How important that is will depend on how your surrounding applications are using these Consul services.

I cannot think of a way to avoid that imprecision as long as you are declaring all of your nodes with a single `resource` block. You could potentially avoid this by using a separate `resource "consul_node"` block for each node, but that would require you to fix exactly how many instances you have as part of the module, rather than having it be declared dynamically by an input variable.